# Database trouble in Django: can't reset because of dependencies

Tags: sql, django

I'm trying to reset a database in Django, using:

```
python manage.py reset app
```

but get the following error:

```
Error: Error: app couldn't be reset. Possible reasons:
  * The database isn't running or isn't configured correctly.
  * At least one of the database tables doesn't exist.
  * The SQL was invalid.
Hint: Look at the output of 'django-admin.py sqlreset app'. That's the SQL this command wasn't able to run.
The full error: cannot drop table app_record because other objects depend on it
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

This is what my models.py file looks like:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, db_index=True)
    year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Class(models.Model):
    record = models.ForeignKey(Record)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.id
```

I get that I need to use the DROP... CASCADE command in the SQL that deletes and recreates the database (the output of django-admin.py).

But how can I edit that SQL directly from models.py?

---

**UPDATE**

OK, I figured out how to delete tables manually (the database is postgres), have noted it here for anyone with the same problem:

```
python manage.py dbshell 
# drop table app_record cascade; 
# \q 
python manage.py reset app
```

Would still like to know if anyone has a better way to do it, though :)

Comment: What command are you typing to get that?  `python manage.py reset app`?  Or are you trying to reset the particular table?

Comment: Sorry - yes, "python manage.py reset app".

Comment: A simple solution would be just to use the DROP... CASCADE command manually, then recreate the database... can anyone give me an example of how to do that?

Comment: OK, I figured out how to do it manually (the database is postgres), have noted it here for anyone with the same problem:

python manage.py dbshell
# drop table app_record cascade;
# \q
python manage.py reset app

Would still like to know if anyone has a better way to do it, though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way to fully reset a Django database is using [django-extensions](http://code.google.com/p/django-command-extensions/).

It has a `reset_db` command that supports all Django's default database backends.

```
python manage.py reset_db
```

If you're using Django 1.2+ you should explicitly define the database you want to reset. If your project only uses one database, you should probably set `--router=default`

Comment: Actually this also does not work on a heroku shared database (which is how I came upon this problem).

Comment: The question specifically asks to reset an app, not the entire database. This is not a good answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

I use a little unix pipeline that adds CASCADE to all the DROP statements.

```
python manage.py sqlreset myapp | sed 's/DROP TABLE \(.*\);/DROP TABLE \1 CASCADE;/g' | \
psql --username myusername mydbname
```

Comment: This is awesome. As an addition, one can use `manage.py dbshell` instead of `psql --username myusername mydbname`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of DROP TABLE CASCADE is that it just remove a foreign keys on related tables - after syncdb this relation is not recreated.
I found no way to recreate the particular model's tables, so I'm reseting whole application by recreating schema:

```
  DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE;
  CREATE SCHEMA "public" AUTHORIZATION "owner of database";
```

That should work only with database that supports schema, e.g. postgresql

Answer (score 1):

Using the details in other answers, I made a bash function that I dropped into ~/.bash_profile (on Mac OS X).

```
django_reset () { python mainsite/manage.py sqlreset "$*" | sed 's/DROP TABLE \(.*\);/DROP TABLE \1 CASCADE;/g' | mainsite/manage.py dbshell ; }
```

Then just run this command in the terminal from your root code directory (so the path to mainsite/manage.py makes sense).

```
django_reset myappA myappB
```

And it'll execute!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way. I'm using sqlite3 that comes by default in Django.
To reset table to default.
**python manage.py flush --database=default**
after this you will need to use the syncdb command again.